# SMOP bad conversion

Tags: python, matlab

I'm using [smop](https://github.com/victorlei/smop) python script to convert a matlab code in python.

In my test matlab code, I've got this:

```
a=10^6*[355,355,373,373,373,373,373]'
```

and it generates me to

```
a = 10 ** 6 * [355,355,373,373,373,373,373].T
```

first of all the problem of `.T`

I need to convert to

```
a = [355,355,373,373,373,373,373]
a=numpy.asarray(a).T.tolist()
```

Then the other, much serious then the other,

```
10 ** 6 * [355,355,373,373,373,373,373]
```

does not multiply each element of the array with 10^6 but replicate 10^6 times each element of the array.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in Python the operator `*` is polymorphic. If the operands are numeric it returns the product of both numbers, but if one operand is an integer (say `n`) and the other is a sequence (namely a string, list or tuple) it concatenates the sequence `n` times and returns the resulting sequence. It is also worth noticing that if one operand is numeric and the other one is a Numpy array, `*` performs element-wise multiplication:

```
>>> 5*2
10
>>> 'ha'*3
hahaha
>>> [1]*4
[1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> ('a', .5)*3
('a', 0.5, 'a', 0.5, 'a', 0.5)
>>> .1*numpy.array([10, 20, 30])
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Try to rewrite your code like this:

```
>>> a = (10**6*numpy.array([355, 355, 373, 373, 373, 373, 373])).reshape(-1, 1).tolist()
>>> a
[[355000000],
 [355000000],
 [373000000],
 [373000000],
 [373000000],
 [373000000],
 [373000000]]
```

Comment: so smop has a big issue. i can't convert all the multiplication inside my big matlab code.

Comment: @JackTurky numpy has [element-wise multiplication](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html)

Comment: @excaza: You are absolutely right, I missed to mention in my original post that if one operand is numeric and the other is a NumPy array, `*` performs element-wise multiplication. I've edited my answer including this information.